# Creating a new column with the number of columns where condition is met

Tags: powerbi, where-clause, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table:

| ID | DATE | ADDRESS | TEST_1 | TEST_2 | TEST_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01.01.19 | XYZ | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 12346 | 02.05.19 | ZYX | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

Now, I want to add a new column to the table that counts the number of times a test returned TRUE for each row. Like:

| ID | DATE | ADRESS | TEST_1 | TEST_2 | TEST_3 | COUNT_TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01.01.19 | XYZ | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | 2 |
| 12346 | 02.05.19 | ZYX | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 1 |

For each DATE and ID are reported test results.

How can I add the new column summing the number of TRUE tests for each row?

I tried to add the new column in numerous ways but nothing seems to work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried:
`=COUNTA(FILTER(table,table[column1] = TRUE || table[column2] = TRUE || table[column3] = TRUE || ...))`
and got "COUNTA function only accepts a column reference as an agrument"

I also tried:
`=COUNTA(FILTER(CONCATENATE(table[column1],table[column2],table[column3],....),CONCATENATE(table[column1],table[column2],table[column3],....) = "TRUE"))`
and got "too many agruments were passed to the concatenate function. Maximum arguments for the function is 2"

I also tried:
`=COUNTA(table[column1]) + COUNTA(table[column2]) + COUNTA(table[column3])`
and got "COUNTA only accepts a column reference as an argument"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column using this below DAX code-

```
Column = 
 if(your_table_name[TEST_1],1,0) +
 if(your_table_name[TEST_2],1,0) +
 if(your_table_name[TEST_3],1,0)
```

Here is the output-

[image]